# codeigniter routes is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have the following problem with CodeIgniter. I'm trying to setup a menu, and using route config to load the proper content but from some reason it's not working.

I have CodeIgniter setup under:

```
http://localhost/new/CodeIgniter/
```

My config file looks like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/new/CodeIgniter/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

My route config looks like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home/home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['home'] = 'Home/home';
$route['compare'] = 'Home/home';
$route['signin'] = 'Home/home';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

And this is my Home controler:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct(); 
} 

public function index() 
{
    $this->home();
}

public function home()
{
    $this->load->model('home_model');

    $this->load->view('header_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('nav_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer_view', $data);
}

public function compare()
{
    $this->load->model('home_model');

    $this->load->view('header_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('nav_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer_view', $data);
}

public function signin()
{
    $this->load->model('home_model');

    $this->load->view('header_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('nav_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer_view', $data);
}   

public function about()
{
    $this->load->model('home_model');

    $this->load->view('header_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('nav_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer_view', $data);
}   
}
```

When I access http://localhost/new/CodeIgniter/ I can see the home page, but none of the following are working:

```
http://localhost/new/CodeIgniter/home
http://localhost/new/CodeIgniter/compare
http://localhost/new/CodeIgniter/signin
http://localhost/new/CodeIgniter/about
```

Does anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

The error is the following:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /new/CodeIgniter/home was not found on this server.
```

This is my httaccess

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
<IfModule ModRewite>
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: you need a default controller

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron if I remove the defaul controller I get the following error message: "Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file."

Comment: Y, sry, Try `http://localhost/new/CodeIgniter/Home/home` or `http://localhost/new/CodeIgniter/Home/compare`

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron for Home/home the error is the same as the one mentioned in the post "Not Found"

Comment: ok try using this url http://localhost/new/CodeIgniter/index.php/home
OR 
http://localhost/new/CodeIgniter/index.php/compare
If its work issue with htacess

Comment: I think this issue may be you may not added htaccess to remove index.php from url. Did you tried like this  `http://localhost/new/CodeIgniter/index.php/home`

Comment: @user1048123 index.php/home is working. But how can I get rid of index.php. How should I update the route config?

Comment: good. This is old one but it will help
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: Write this in ur htaccess file to get rid of index.php [link](https://jsfiddle.net/0kkf452r/).Make sure you have mod_rewrite enbled.

Comment: @Bugfixer I still get File Not Found error

Comment: did u check ur httpd.conf file.Mod_rewrite enable and allowoveride  ALL. Then restart ur httpd.You dont need to mention base_url in config file. keep it empty.

Comment: hii try my htaccess code...:)

Comment: @CristianBalint You need to add new htaccess in main directory do not touch the application htaccess.

Comment: @Bugfixer my httpd.conf is empty. Can you please give the exact syntax?

Comment: @CristianBalint
i think you mod_rewrite is not enable
check this if you are using ubuntu
http://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache

Comment: @Bugfixer not sure, how can I check?

Answer (score 0):

I think a .htaccess file is missing. Create a new file with this content and save it in the CI root.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /new/CodeIgniter
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I added the line RewriteBase. You have CI in subfolders. :)

Comment: Open the file /config/config.php and edit the line $config['log_threshold'] = 2; And reload the browser and then check the logfile in /application/logs/log-xxx.php - you'll get something like ERROR - 2015-07-31 10:20:08 --> 404 Page Not Found --> xxx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you mod_rewrite enabled (check through [phpinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957731/codeigniter-where-to-put-htaccess) that is enable or not).

For enable mod_rewrite check following

1. For  [Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache)
2. For [window](http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting/)

And add this .htacess

[where to add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957731/codeigniter-where-to-put-htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

in your root folder