# Codeigniter routing using base_url

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I am using the Pagination library in Codeigniter, and the links it creates are exactly what I'm looking for. When I click on the link to go to the next page I get a 404.

My base url (index page) is: `http://localhost/foo`

My routing is:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'main';
$route['page/(:num)'] = 'main/page/$1';
```

I want to be able to go to the url: `http://localhost/foo/page/2` to get the second page. `main` is the controller. `page` is a function inside `main`.

I *can* type in the url `http://localhost/foo/index.php/main/page/2` and get to the correct page, but I **do not** want to have the `index.php/main` in the url.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742035/codeigniter-routes-is-not-working/31742564#31742564

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong. If you want to remove the index.php from the url:

Leave in blank **$config['index_page']** attibute on the **application/config/config.php** file and make sure that you have a .htaccess that contains

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also make sure the apache server has mod_rewrite enabled and in the configuration of apache AllowOverride attribute it's been set to All

Answer (score 0):

In you Controller(In pagination code) `$config['base_url']` should be

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'foo/page/';
```

In routes.php

```
$route['page/(:num)'] = 'main/page/$1';
$route['page'] = 'main/page';//add this line
```

In `.htaccess`,(Place outside application folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

> **Note:** To use `base_url()` in `config/autoload.php`
>
> ```
> $autoload['helper'] = array('url');//url
> ```
>
> and in `config/config.php`, (Change this)
>
> ```
> $config['base_url']   = '';
> $config['index_page'] = '';
> ```